# Run istioctl alongside kubectl under fish shell

Tags: shell, kubernetes, fish, kubectl, istio

I've just had a try with `istio` on my `kubernetes` cluster

However, i got some hiccup on setting up bookinfo sample app. This command ran perfectly fine under bash shell, but not fish:

```
kubectl apply -f <(istioctl kube-inject -f samples/apps/bookinfo/bookinfo.yaml)
```

I got this error:

```
Invalid redirection target: < (istioctl kube-inject -f samples/apps/bookinfo/bookinfo.yaml)
```

Any idea on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Although there's an alternate way to do that:

`istioctl kube-inject -f samples/apps/bookinfo/bookinfo.yaml  | kubectl apply -f -`

But it's more convenient for new user if they just need to copy/paste the commands.

Answer (score 3):

Fish does not support that process substitution syntax. We do provide an alternative although it isn't perfect. See `help psub` from a fish prompt. If `kubectl` recognizes the idiom of `-` to mean read from stdin I would recommend rewriting that as

```
istioctl kube-inject -f samples/apps/bookinfo/bookinfo.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

as proposed by @Tuannvm. Frankly, I would recommend that variant as the canonical way to perform that operation as the `<(a_command)` syntax isn't needed AFAICT. There may be some strange situation where it is helpful but I can't think of one off the top of my head and I've been using UNIX for more than 30 years.